# How to use Pronexus DLLs

Tags: com

I am supposed to do a IVR project using Pronexus. After downloading their DLLs, my code hit COMExceptions regularly. I have searched the net and learned about Component Object Model. Now I am in trouble as I do not know how should I write my codes to extend from the DLLs that is accessing unmanaged codes.

So my question is, can someone point me to a direction how can I proceed from here? Should I learn how to code with COM libraries? Any good sources to recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a clue from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973872.aspx (good read for developer new to Component Object Model)